# Proper use of platform variables in generator expressions

Tags: cmake

I have used cmake's [`WIN32`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.18/variable/WIN32.html?highlight=win32) variable extensively in manners such as:

```
if (${WIN32)
   ...
endif()
```

However, I am not sure how to properly use the `WIN32` variable in a generator expression. Naively I tried this:

```
target_link_libraries(mytarget
    PUBLIC
        $<$<AND:${SOME_DEPENDENCY_ENABLED}, ${WIN32}>:bcrypt>
        $<$<AND:${SOME_OTHER_DEPENDENCY_ENABLED}, ${WIN32}>:wsock32>
)
```

This results in a cmake error:

```
CMake Error:
  Error evaluating generator expression:

    $<AND:OFF,>

  Parameters to $<AND> must resolve to either '0' or '1'.
```

I understand that the problem lies in the fact that `WIN32` is set to `True` when the target system is Windows - but **not** set to `False` if not. Therefore, on a non-Windows system the generator expression expands to an invalid expression.

What is the proper way of getting either `True` or `False` out of `WIN32` to use it in a generator expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a variable `var` can be checked with `if(${var})` or `if(var)`, then using expression

```
$<BOOL:${var}>
```

would be evaluated to 1 if the check succeed and to 0 otherwise.

This is exactly what generator expressions expects as a boolean value: 0 or 1.

E.g.

```
$<$<BOOL:${WIN32}>:bcrypt>
```

is equivalent to

```
if(WIN32)
  # use value 'bcrypt'
else()
  # use empty value
endif()
```

---

Note also, that *generator expressions* are not intended to be used as a replacement for **any** `if` condition.

The primary purpose of generator expressions to create conditionals dependent on things(variables, properties) specific for a **configuration** type (Release, Debug and so on). Because on multi-configuration generators a configuration type is not known when `CMakeLists.txt` is read, one cannot use plain `if` for such kind of variables and properties.

Comment: How do the line `$<$<BOOL:${WIN32}>:bcrypt>` can return something for Linux as well? Is there any solution for that? In other words, I need to return something different for Windows and Linux.